# Webmin -> Virtualmin -> Let's Encrypt -- Getting error about e-mail when registering SSL

Tags: ssl, certificate, webmin, letsencrypt

I am using
*Ubuntu 16.04 -> LAMP -> Webmin 1.810 -> Virtualmin 5.04 -> Let's Encrypt(Certbot)*
to handle SSL certificates and the CA certification gets pushed through resulting in precious green keylocks next to my websites URL's. However everytime i request for an certificate it gives an error about not having a correct E-mail registered for urgent notification. Should there be a file in which i can setup some variables/constant containing such details?

I also wonder where i can change the generated certificate information.

Comment: The Let's Encrypt documentation is very good, it indicates, how you specify the email account.  have you taken a moment to read it?

Comment: I googled around for it. I just read the docs on their website but i can't find anything on the mather. I am currently reading: http://letsencrypt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html  I actually assumed the Virtualmin version would have an different approach. However I will keep searching. (i have searched for an hour or so earlier today so help is welcome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the following command-line option:

```
-m EMAIL, --email EMAIL
                        Email used for registration and recovery contact.
                        (default: None)
```

You can make this easier by adding the following to your configuration file:

```
#Uncomment and update to register with the specified e-mail address  
#email = foo@example.com
```

If you don't want reminder emails just use this instead:

```
 --register-unsafely-without-email
                        Specifying this flag enables registering an account
                        with no email address. This is strongly discouraged,
                        because in the event of key loss or account compromise
                        you will irrevocably lose access to your account. You
                        will also be unable to receive notice about impending
                        expiration or revocation of your certificates. Updates
                        to the Subscriber Agreement will still affect you, and
                        will be effective 14 days after posting an update to
                        the web site. (default: False)
```

The source for all this information was the [Let's Encrypt Certbot User Guide](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html).

Comment: Fixed. Use `\#` :)

Comment: You could also have indented for code within the quote. That is: `>`, space and then 4 spaces for code. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In my case Lets Encrypt was installed in /opt/letsencrypt/  so i had to place the cli.ini there. Because i installed 'Certbot' with the `/opt/letsencrypt/certbot-auto` script i also have to call certbot-auto like `./certbot-auto` instead of `certbot-auto` from the Ubuntu terminal.
After that i ran:

```
cd /opt/letsencrypt/
./certbot-auto -c cli.ini
```

and filled in one domain of a virtual server i have running and after confirming the terms i can now request SSL certificates from within Virtualmin without getting bothered by an error. This should in theory mean that i will get urgent notifications from now on.

Also like to thank you guys for the quick advice :)